# Kafka JDBC connector bulk mode

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

kafka-connect-jdbc connector continuously sending same records in bulk mode after the specific interval of time.Here are my connector properties:

```
    name=test-mssql-jdbc-autoincrement
    connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
    tasks.max=1
 connection.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/TESTDB;user=sa;password=sa12345
    query=SELECT * FROM WF_PROCESS
    mode=bulk
    topic.prefix=TEST-
    key.serializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
    value.serializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
    table.blacklist=trace_xe_action_map,trace_xe_event_map
```

Answer (score 2):

Bulk mode is supposed to send all the records every time poll method is called. The main usecase of using bulk mode is of taking periodic backups of database tables. You can configure the frequency of backup by tuning poll.interval.ms.

To avoid this, do not use bulk mode. Instead use "timestamp+incrementing" OR "timestamp" OR "incrementing mode". For more details, you can refer [this](http://docs.confluent.io/2.0.0/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/index.html#incremental-query-modes) link.

Comment: does it clean up the previous batch of data in the topic or does it append to it?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to configure [incremental query modes](http://docs.confluent.io/2.0.0/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/index.html#incremental-query-modes). Basically Kafka connector needs a way to figure out how to get incremental data every time you fire query.

Comment: Is there a way to stop connector while running in bulk mode. What I want is to ingest records only single time in bulk mode.

Comment: high latency then stop